# Identify source of CSS style with Google dev tool

Tags: css

So I am trying to apply a style to a specific div of my web mapping project. But I don't get why it's not working. I want that to specific div to be transparent, but it's overriten by a rule that gives the background-color #808080 and I can not locate the rule responsible for it. The dev tool says only  for source.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WURv.png)

How can I find the source of the rule background-color: #808080!important?

Comment: Are you use bootstrap?

Comment: @MrSalamikuchen Can you share html and releant css, please?

Comment: Try to set to the class titlePane the background-color

Comment: @Maik Lowery: Hi, here's the link to the page. https://wasserwiki.eu/Wasserwiki_App

Comment: try adding body before .esriPopup .titlePane like this (body .esriPopup .titlePane)..
or any parent class of .esriPopup
see if this works

Answer (score 1):

When two similar styles (in the different selectors) have `!important`, the style be applied that its `specificity` has more priority. For that reason when you add body before `.esriPopup`, the priority of your style is more.

For more information about it, you can read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

The tip from @sanket is the solution:

```
body .esriPopup .titlePane {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Adding "body" did the trick.